# PHP Delete XML Node by Attribute

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Have tried numerous examples on SO but none have worked.

Goal: Remove a node (*unit*) and it's children, by specific *id=*

**filename.xml**

```
<archive>
  <unit id="0424670018">
    <data>Blah blah blah #1</data>
    <gdate>2018-05-28 00:42:46</gdate>
</unit>
  <unit id="0450170018">
    <data>Blah blah blah #2</data>
    <gdate>2018-05-28 00:45:01</gdate>
  </unit>
</archive>
```

Code used, not sure why it does not work when loaded:

```
$id = '0450170018';
$file = 'filename.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($file);

foreach($xml->archive as $fileload){
    if($fileload->unit['@id'] == $id){
        $dom = dom_import_simplexml($fileload);
        $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the node using Xpath. It allows to fetch the matching node(s) directly.

```
$id = '0450170018';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load('filename.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
foreach ($xpath->evaluate("//unit[@id='$id']") as $unitNode) {
  $unitNode->parentNode->removeChild($unitNode);
}
$document->save('filename.xml');
```

Comment: This works well too and your counter argument above has me choose this version instead. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "DOMDocument" class

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('filename.xml');
$xml = $doc->documentElement;
$id = '0450170018';
$domNodeList = $xml->getElementsByTagname('unit'); 
foreach ( $domNodeList as $domElement ) { 

    $valueID = $domElement->getAttribute('id'); 
    if($valueID == $id)
    {
        $xml->removeChild($domElement);
    }
}
$doc->save('filename.xml');
```

Comment: Be careful, `getElementsByTagname()` returns a "live" result (it changes if you modify the DOM). If you remove multiple nodes, this might not work as expected.

Comment: @ThW I will only ever remove one node at a time via a delete form posting the $id so, thus far it has been successful. I am going to test your code as well and then decide. Thx.